# How to use ConvexOptimization on a function constructed from data?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, interpolation, computational-geometry

Given the following data points sampled from a convex function, how could I construct a convex function that can be minimized using `ConvexOptimization`?

```
mypts = {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 2.01}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}};
g = Interpolation[ mypts, InterpolationOrder -> 2 ];
Plot3D[ g[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2} ]
ConvexOptimization[ g[x, y] + x + y, {x >= 0, x <= 2, y >= 0, y <= 2}, {x, y} ]
```

[image]

The error message is:

> ConvexOptimization: The function InterpolatingFunction[...] is neither convex or concave so the curvature of the objective function ... cannot be determined.

I tried option `InterpolationOrder -> 1`, but got the same error message.

I could use `NMinimize`, but I hope to use `ConvexOptimization`, which should be considerably faster for larger problems.

I am considering generating a convex hull using the data points:

```
R = ConvexHullRegion[mypts]
Show[ListPlot3D[mypts], HighlightMesh[R, Style[2, Opacity[0.5]]]]
```

[image]

Can anyone help on how to **convert a subset of the surfaces of a convex hull into a convex function** that can then serve as an input for `ConvexOptimization`?  Perhaps this is a long shot. I hope there is a shortcut to construct a convex function from data points and then apply `ConvexOptimization`. The function doesn't need to be smooth, just need to be acceptable by `ConvexOptimization`. Thank you for your read and help.

Comment: Use: `NMinimize[{g[x, y] + x + y, {x >= 0, x <= 2, y >= 0, y <= 2}}, {x, y}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create convex function we can use `InterpolatingPolynomial` as follows

```
mypts = {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 2}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 2,
    1}, {2, 0, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}; g = 
 Interpolation[mypts, InterpolationOrder -> 2]; {zc = 
  Table[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2, .4}, {y, 0, 2, .4}], 
 xc = Table[x, {x, 0, 2, .4}], yc = Table[y, {y, 0, 2, .4}]};

yinterp = 
  Map[InterpolatingPolynomial[Transpose[{yc, #}], y] &, zc] // Chop;

g1 = InterpolatingPolynomial[Transpose[{xc, yinterp}], x] // Chop

Plot3D[g1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Optimization

```
ConvexOptimization[
 g1 + x + y, {x >= 0, x <= 2, y >= 0, y <= 2}, {x, y}]

Out[]= {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5}
```

Update 1. We also can construct convex function using `FindFit` as follows

```
model = a + b1 x + b2 y + c1 x^2 + c2 y^2 + d x y; ff = 
 FindFit[mypts, model, {a, b1, b2, c1, c2, d}, {x, y}]

(*Out[]= {a -> 1.99972, b1 -> -2.0025, b2 -> -1.99917, c1 -> 1.00167, 
 c2 -> 1.00167, d -> -0.0025}*)

 g2 = model /. ff

(*Out[]= 1.99972 - 2.0025 x + 1.00167 x^2 - 1.99917 y - 0.0025 x y + 
 1.00167 y^2*)

 ConvexOptimization[
 g2 + x + y, {x >= 0, x <= 2, y >= 0, y <= 2}, {x, y}]

Out[]= {x -> 0.501039, y -> 0.499377}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for your suggestion!  However, if the data points are slightly perturbed while maintaining the existence of a convex interpolation, your suggestion does not work anymore.  Here is the perturbed data: ```mypts = {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 2.01}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1,2, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}};```   Mathematica can verify the convexity: ```FunctionConvexity[{g1, {x >= 0, x <= 2, y >= 0, y <= 2}}, {x, y}]``` returns 1, but ConvexOptimization returns an error.

Comment: We can use `ConvexOptimization[
 Rationalize[g1 // Expand // Simplify, 10^-2] + x + y, {x >= 0, 
  x <= 2, y >= 0, y <= 2}, {x, y}]`

Comment: I appreciate your help, Alex!  Your method works for some special cases, but not in general.  Suppose the data is:  ```mypts={{0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1.05}, {0, 2, 2}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}};``` Then I will need to rationalize the result using a coarser approximation.   My original problem has many iterative minimizations, so I wanted to avoid introducing approximation errors.   I am hoping to make the Convex Hull method work.  Although Convex Hull doesn't give me a smooth surface, I can ensure convexity when using ```ConvexOptimization```

Comment: @newOwen We have 9 points in 2D. In theory we can't make very precise approximation with 9 points only.  Anyway, please, see Update 1 to my answer with second algorithm to construct convex function from your data.

Comment: This is a clever solution. Thanks, Alex!   I like your solution when a parametric model is a good approximation.  For general applications, basis functions may be hard to determine and I wish to use non-parametric models, such as Interpolation function in convex optimization.  But I guess ```ConvexOptimization``` is pretty strict on the function   to be optimized.

Comment: @newOwen Yes, you are right.  `ConvexOptimization` is a new function with very restricted properties.